# TYPO3 v10: rowCount in backend layout seems not to work anymore

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-10.x

I have an issue regarding the backend layouts in TYPO3 10 LTS. In v9 I was able to hide rows in the backend by setting the rowCount to a smaller number than there are rows. I used this to hide the irre-elements for the users. In v10 all rows are shown, no matter which number I set the rowCount. Is this a bug by the new version or am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
   title = Default
   config {
       backend_layout {
           colCount = 1
           rowCount = 1
           rows {
               1 {
                   columns {
                       1 {
                           name = content
                           colPos = 0
                       }
                   }
               }
               2  {
                   columns {
                       1 {
                           name = elements from elements (should not be visible)
                           colPos = 123
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this ever worked, this was a bug, that has been fixed now. Actually the rowCount and colCount parameters were meant to define a specific number of rows for the backend layout wizard, so that you can set things like rowSpan and colSpan.

The number of visible rows should always have been determined by the actual rows defined in the configuration. If you want to remove columns this should be done with colPos_list: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It kind of worked. The label now says "no edit access" and the background color is greyed out, but I still see the "+ Content"-Button in there and I can still add content elements.

Comment: Are you in the new page module? If so, please try, if it is the same with the legacy page module. If not, this might be a bug of the new page module, since a disabled column should not show any buttons and/or content elements at all.